# More than one row with the given identifier was found while I'm trying to merge the object

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, spring

I'm facing the following error in Hibernate : **More than one row with the given identifier was found** while I'm trying to merge the object.

Details :

1. I'm using Spring 2.5, Hibernate 3.2 and my application deployed on
   Websphere ver 7.x
2. I applied the DB Session per HTTP request methodology (not the
   spring implementation) but I used the ThreadLocal to save the
   session to be used again within the current HTTP request, and once
   the response is ready to be sent to the client I have a HTTPFilter
   to close any opened session in this Thread.
3. I got the error once I have a bulk operation on the DB within one
   HTTP request (Deleting, Updating, Merging, Inserting,.....)
4. I used the JNDI datasource managed by Websphere itself
5. I was thinking like following: At the starting point of my request,
   I asked the session factory to provide me a session instance, and I
   used this session in my request until I closed it at the end of my
   request processing. and the hibernate merge method try to load the
   object before merging it, once the query for loading is executed:
   the exception is thrown telling me that (More than one row with the
   given identifier was found), for me this means that the object is
   loaded to the current session before, so the first stupid idea was
   to flush and close the current session before merging and start a
   new one just for this merging, I did that but I faced the same
   error, that means I was thinking wrong from the beginning.
6. The second approach I'm trying to follow is to separate this bulk
   operation to multi operations done directly in separate ajax request
   (Suppose I have a grid with update and delete functionality for each
   row, I allow the user to update and delete whatever he wants and I
   cache these changes until the user click "apply" button to apply all
   thees changes, the new Idea is: once the user tried to delete a row
   a new HTTP request (with DB session) will be responsible for
   deleting this row in the database, in this case no more need to the
   apply button because the modifications a reflected directly to the
   DB)

The DB Structure (MS SQLServer 2008):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Correspondence_Site](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Name] [varchar](500) NULL,
[Parent_Id] [int] NULL,
[Is_Active] [bit] NOT NULL,
[Dept_Id] [int] NULL, CONSTRAINT [PK_Correspondence_Sites] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (  [Id] ASC )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Correspondence_Site]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Correspondence_Sites_Correspondence_Sites] FOREIGN KEY([Parent_Id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Correspondence_Site] ([Id])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Correspondence_Site] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Correspondence_Sites_Correspondence_Sites]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Correspondence_Site] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Correspondence_Site_Is_Active]  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [Is_Active]



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Dep_Correspondence_Site](
[Department_Id] [int] NOT NULL,
[Correspondence_Site_Id] [int] NOT NULL,
[Serial] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Site_Order] [int] NULL,
[Security_Level] [int] NULL) ON [PRIMARY]


ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Dep_Correspondence_Site]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK__Dep_Correspondence_Sites_Correspondence_Sites] FOREIGN KEY([Correspondence_Site_Id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Correspondence_Site] ([Id])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Dep_Correspondence_Site] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK__Dep_Correspondence_Sites_Correspondence_Sites]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Dep_Correspondence_Site]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Dep__Correspondence_Sites_Departments] FOREIGN KEY([Department_Id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Department] ([Id])


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Department](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Description] [varchar](80) NOT NULL,
[Parent] [int] NULL,
[Type] [int] NOT NULL,
[Prefix] [varchar](100) NULL,
[Ldap_Prefix] [varchar](200) NULL,
[Serial_Prefix] [varchar](20) NULL,
[Manager_Id] [int] NULL,
[Assistant_Id] [int] NULL,
[Telephone_Numbers] [varchar](100) NULL,
[Fax_Numbers] [varchar](100) NULL,
[SMS_Max_Time] [int] NULL,
[Email_Max_Time] [int] NULL,
[Has_Correspondence] [bit] NULL,
[Email] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Logo_Image_Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Code] [int] NULL,
[Incoming_Fields] [int] NULL,
[Outgoing_Fields] [int] NULL,
[Internal_Memo_Fields] [int] NULL,
[Folder_Path] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
[Department_Last_Data_Update] [datetime] NULL, 
CONSTRAINT [PK_Departments] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Theses three tables are connected like the following:

1. Each department has 0..n correspondence_site
2. Each correspondence_site can be connected to 0..n department
3. The table **Dep_Correspondence_Site** to allow the above relation to be done with some extra fields like (Serial, SecurityLevel, Order,..)

When I generated the Mapping in the hibernate the following classes had been generated:

1. Department.java, DepartmentDAO.java and Department.hbm.xml
2. CorrespondenceSite.java, CorrespondenceSiteDAO.java and CorrespondenceSite.hbm.xml
3. DepCorrespondenceSite.java, DepCorrespondenceSiteDAO.java, DepCorrespondenceSiteId.java, DepCorrespondenceSite.hbm.xml

The DepCorrespondenceSiteId is the composite id.

```
DepCorrespondenceSiteId dcsID = new DepCorrespondenceSiteId();
        dcsID.setDepartment(department);
        dcsID.setCorrespondenceSite(fullCorrespondenceSite.mainCorrespondenceSite);
        DepCorrespondenceSite dcs = new DepCorrespondenceSite();
        dcs.setId(dcsID);
        dcs.setSerial(fullCorrespondenceSite.mainCorrespondenceSite.getSerial());
        dcs.setSiteOrder(new Integer(mainOrder));
        dcs.setSecurityLevel(fullCorrespondenceSite.mainCorrespondenceSite.getSecurityLevel());
        depCorrespondenceSiteDAO.update(dcs);
        // Save sub correspondence site in database
        for(CorrespondenceSite subCorrespondenceSite: fullCorrespondenceSite.subCorrespondenceSites){
            dcsID = new DepCorrespondenceSiteId();
            dcsID.setDepartment(department);
            dcsID.setCorrespondenceSite(subCorrespondenceSite);
            dcs = new DepCorrespondenceSite();
            dcs.setId(dcsID);
            dcs.setSerial(subCorrespondenceSite.getSerial());
            dcs.setSecurityLevel(subCorrespondenceSite.getSecurityLevel());
            dcs.setSiteOrder(new Integer(subOrder));
            depCorrespondenceSiteDAO.update(dcs);
            subOrder ++;
        }
```

In the loop, and when I tried to update the dcs I got the following error (this error not for all records, some records are updated correctly and t exception is thrown for the the forth record for example)

```
[2/5/12 11:36:25:489 AST] 00000015 DefaultLoadEv I org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener onLoad Error performing load command
                             org.hibernate.HibernateException: More than one row with the given identifier was found: com.ebla.moi.correspondence.model.entity.db.DepCorrespondenceSiteId@cc7f, for class: com.ebla.moi.correspondence.model.entity.db.DepCorrespondenceSite
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:69)
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:42)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3044)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:395)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:375)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:139)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:179)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:103)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:878)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:815)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:229)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:120)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:53)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:677)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:661)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:665)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$23.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:765)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.execute(HibernateTemplate.java:372)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.merge(HibernateTemplate.java:762)
at com.ebla.moi.correspondence.model.entity.db.DepCorrespondenceSiteDAO.update(DepCorrespondenceSiteDAO.java:56)
at com.ebla.moi.correspondence.view.bean.admin.departments.DepartmentVariablesBean.saveCorrespondenceSites(DepartmentVariablesBean.java:1438)
at com.ebla.moi.correspondence.view.bean.admin.departments.DepartmentVariablesBean.saveAdministration(DepartmentVariablesBean.java:1007)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:159)
at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
at com.sun.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:68)
at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:99)
at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:770)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:372)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:458)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:763)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:82)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.JsfLifecycleExecutor.apply(JsfLifecycleExecutor.java:18)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.ReceiveSendUpdates.renderCycle(ReceiveSendUpdates.java:132)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.ReceiveSendUpdates.service(ReceiveSendUpdates.java:74)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.RequestVerifier.service(RequestVerifier.java:31)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.common.standard.PathDispatcherServer.service(PathDispatcherServer.java:24)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.BasicAdaptingServlet.service(BasicAdaptingServlet.java:16)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.PathDispatcher.service(PathDispatcher.java:23)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.SessionDispatcher.service(SessionDispatcher.java:53)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.SessionVerifier.service(SessionVerifier.java:26)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.PathDispatcher.service(PathDispatcher.java:23)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:131)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.xmlhttp.BlockingServlet.service(BlockingServlet.java:56)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1597)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:131)
at com.ebla.moi.correspondence.util.filters.CharsetFilter.doFilter(CharsetFilter.java:28)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:934)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:91)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:864)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1583)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:445)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:504)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:301)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1604)
```

The update function in the DepCorrespondenceSiteDAO.java:

```
public void update(DepCorrespondenceSite transientInstance){
    log.debug("updating DepCorrespondenceSite instance");
    try {
        if(transientInstance.getId() != null){
            getMyHibernateTemplate().merge(transientInstance);
        }else{
            getMyHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(transientInstance);
        }
        log.debug("update successful");
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        log.error("update failed", re);
        throw re;
    }
}
```

The DepCorrespondenceSiteId.java

```
public class DepCorrespondenceSiteId implements java.io.Serializable {
private Department department;
private CorrespondenceSite correspondenceSite;

public DepCorrespondenceSiteId() {
}

public DepCorrespondenceSiteId(Department department,
        CorrespondenceSite correspondenceSite) {
    this.department = department;
    this.correspondenceSite = correspondenceSite;
}

public Department getDepartment() {
    return this.department;
}

public void setDepartment(Department department) {
    this.department = department;
}

public CorrespondenceSite getCorrespondenceSite() {
    return this.correspondenceSite;
}

public void setCorrespondenceSite(CorrespondenceSite correspondenceSite) {
    this.correspondenceSite = correspondenceSite;
}
}
```

Please help me. 
Regards

Comment: Show us the code causing the exception, and the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Thank you JBNizet for your instance response, I modified the question body by adding the code and stacktrace

Comment: The exception occurs when loading a DepCorrespondenceSite: you have several rows with the same ID in database. What's the PK of the corresponding table? How is the DepCorrespondenceSiteId class defined?

Comment: At the DB level the DepCorrespondenceSite table has the (Department_Id & Correspondence_Site_Id) as a primary key, so no duplicates here... The DepCorrespondenceSiteId is defined to handle the composite id of the table (DepCorrespondenceSite) and has only two data members (private Department department; private CorrespondenceSite correspondenceSite;)

Comment: Please check the question body again.

Comment: Read http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#components-compositeid: You can use a component as an identifier of an entity class. Your component class must satisfy certain requirements:

    It must implement java.io.Serializable.

    It must re-implement equals() and hashCode() consistently with the database's notion of composite key equality.

Comment: The equals() and hashCode() are exist but I removed them to prevent making the question too long